# Sonarqube projects are getting disappeared randomly

Tags: sonarqube

We are using SonarQube in our organization behind Apache. We use maven sonar goals in the post build actions in Jenkins. It was working fine till we noticed a weird scenario. Generated projects are getting deleted or disappeared from the Dashboards strangely.

If the corresponding Jenkins jobs is re-triggered, on its completion, the lost or disappeared Sonar Projects gets displayed on the Dashboard.

There are no scheduled jobs to delete any projects older than X number of days.

Any idea ? Thanks.

```
SonarQube V 5.5
MAven : 3.3.9
Jenkins: 2.7.2
```

Comment: The current version is 6.4 and the current LTS is 5.6.6. You're going to have a hard time finding help for any version earlier than that.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam : Yes, we are planning to migrate it 6.1 but not   in near future, so any help or suggestion would be really helpful.